# Testing mapper.py generated syntax confusion

Tags: python-3.x

It is day 5, after gruesome attempts to figure out python env error I am stuck on thsi silly syntax which I have no clue about. Can anyone please help me?

```
    #!/use/bin/env python
    """mapper.py"""
    import sys
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        words = line.split()
    
        for word in words:
            print '%s\t%s' % (word, 1) [syntax error]
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: This is Python 2.x syntax. Add parentheses to your print line to see if it helps (i.e. `print('%s\t%s' % (word, 1))`)

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you so much! @Selcuk I was just wondering why it even gave a syntax error? I have been using this code in python for a while and it was all working fine before I updated python 2.7 to 3.8. I recently started using editors to write python progs before ananconda was my get-to-go editor.